# Java Regex: Allow only one blank space between two words

Tags: java, regex

Hello I'm trying to write a regular expression to implement a simple First Name + Space + Last Name in Java. Two words with only one space between them. The total length (including the white space) of the text should be between 8 and 60 characters. I tried the following but it does not work.

```js
"[a-zA-z][ ][a-zA-Z]{8,60}"
```

Comment: why don't you look for white space that is at least two long [ ]{2,60}

Comment: `^(?=.{8,60}$)[a-zA-Z][ ][a-zA-Z]+$`, I believe `A-z` is a typo.

Comment: Or avoid regex at all `!str.contains("  ") && str.length() <= 60`

Comment: Ok, you may  use `^(?=.{8,60}$)[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$`